# Sublime Text 2 autocompletion shortcut not working

Tags: autocomplete, ide, editor, sublimetext2, shortcut

I'm getting really crazy right now.
The shortcut for autocompletion in Sublime Text 2 (ctrl+space ??) won't work for me.
Every time I press ctrl+space it gives me the last word I typed before.
But the code completion does work while I'm typing.

Anyone that knows how to fix this or what's wrong?

A video to make clear what a mean: http://shots.wouterds.be/ST2-CodeCompletion-Help-0oD220SKlB.mov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular popup isn't Sublime Text 2's built-in autocomplete dialog at all -- it's the [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) code suggestion window.

Sublime Text 2 by itself only offers autocompletion suggestions based on snippets, API-injected completions, `.sublime-completions` files, and words in the buffer (see [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) for more information). SublimeCodeIntel, on the other hand, builds a library of suggestions based on the language you're using and (presumably) the project you're working on. You should be able to tell which window is which by examining the content of the popup versus the content of your working file -- SublimeCodeIntel's suggestions will contain more information (like the `(function)` keyword) and might include words not present in the current file.

SublimeCodeIntel's suggestion list pops up automatically while you're typing, but has a distinct keyboard shortcut listed in your `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeCodeIntel -> Key Bindings -- Default` file. `Ctrl+Space` calls the default autocompletion dialog. You could potentially adjust the completion shortcuts so that `Ctrl+Space` instead raises SublimeCodeIntel's autocompletion list by adding the line...

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "code_intel_auto_complete" }
```

...to your `Preferences -> Key Bindings -- User` file, although doing so might mess up the appearance of the regular autocompletion window.